# «Не знаю куда делось». Запятая не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, цельное-выражение

> Не знаю куда делось. Точно помню, что было.

Запятая перед "куда" не нужна, ибо это цельное по смыслу выражение? Не очень и не всегда могу увидеть эту "цельность смысла" выражения. Как набить глаз?

Comment: Надо не глаз набить, а уши.

Comment: Нет у меня "чуйки" на такие дела. Я бы поставил запятую. Sharon - не поставила. Получается, у неё есть чего-то такое, чего у меня - нет. Печалюсь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем правило:   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

§ 41. **Цельные по смыслу выражения**

Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.

1. Перед **подчинительным союзом или союзным словом** в составе неразложимых сочетаний запятая не ставится. Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и **обычно эквивалентен члену предложения**. Так, в сочетании ***говорит об этом где только может*** выделенные слова имеют значение ‘везде’.

Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных словосочетаний **употреблено не в качестве фразеологизма,** то оно может образовать придаточную часть (обычно неполное предложение) и быть выделено запятыми: Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и не нужно — ‘везде’; Поставить, где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания — ‘где это нужно’.

Диалог был такой:

– *А где "Я"?*

– *Не знаю куда дЕлось* (= не знаю где). Точно помню, что было.

Ударение стоит на глаголе? Нет, у меня ударение падает на оборот, глагол логически не выделен. Кстати, в примере у Розенталя тоже есть произносительная пауза и ударение (но не подчеркнутое), а запятой нет.

**Примечание (не забываем вот о чем)**

Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, **в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания**, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это **исключает формальный подход** к соблюдению правил.

Comment: Спасибо, очень познавательно! Сам не разобрался бы!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста!  Можете считать меня своим личным консультантом. :))

Comment: Как же вы заблуждаетесь. Не любое краткое придаточное так можно оформлять. Оно должно быть устойчивым, в некоторой мере фразеологическим. Ни капли устойчивости в "куда делось" нет, это вообще разговорная фраза, нет там никакой цельности. Взгляните на это примечание Розенталя: https://i.imgur.com/SWX5dWV.png

Comment: Может, анализ пары примеров поможет: *бери что нравится* — не бери то, что нравится, а можешь брать что угодно; *приходить когда вздумается* — не приходить тогда, когда вздумается, а приходить в любое время. В таких случаях "придаточный оборот" становится похож на обстоятельство. Но здесь каждое слово играет роль — заменишь синонимом, и фразеологическая цельность нарушается. В слове "делось" ноль фразеологичности.

Comment: О, так всё сходится. Читаем дальше у Розенталя: Данное правило основано на том, что **фразеологический оборот** не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения. "Куда делось" — это фразеологический оборот? Весело. То есть суммы значений слов "куда" и "делось" там нет... Но она есть. Вы же понимаете, что у меня цель не наехать или т.п., а чтобы вы разобрались, ведь это одна из самых сложных тем. А то решат, что, если ударение не падает на глагол, то запятая не нужна.

Comment: oleedd, есть ПОЛЕ ОТВЕТОВ, есть люди, готовые вас слушать. Почему вы не отвечаете там.  Ну что вам до меня, заблуждаюсь я или нет. Мне  вот кажется. что в половине примеров из Розенталя  по вашей ссылке не надо ставить запятую. Работайте с АУДИТОРИЕЙ, люди будут вам благодарны, оценят ваши знания.  Вы вот не признаете принципа коммуникативности (когда и кому говорим), а он важен. Вы любите однозначность, а тот же Розенталь  призывает вас к гибкости, к конкретности, к учету авторских решений. Это ваш выбор, но не мой.  В другой  ситуации запятую можно было поставить, а здесь необязательно.

Comment: А мне хочется вам помочь, не бросать же вас в беде. Там есть фишка, и она стандартная. Когда фразеологизм, прямое значение не подходит, а подходит переносное. В вашем примере такого не наблюдается, там прямое значение подходит, а переносного нет. Главный критерий — чтобы прямое не подходило. Кстати, когда-то заблуждался в этой теме так же, как и вы, и в этом вина Розенталя, он её плохо (мало) объяснил. *Вы любите однозначность* — нет, просмотрите мои ответы, всегда старался указывать все возможные варианты.

Comment: Не обижайтесь на нас, мы лишь хотим пролить лучик света на правду.

Comment: А с вами, oleedd, лучик вы наш светлый. пожалуй, будет особый разговор, но уже по почте.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, ответ Sharon в этой теме меня обескуражил. Я-то считал, что она просто совершила описку, не поставив запятую в написанном ею когда-то в комментариях этом предложении. А тут…

> *– А где "Я"?*
>
> *– Не знаю куда делось.*

***(Я) Не знаю,** куда **(оно, т. е. «Я») делось.***

Имеем две грамматических основы с разными субъектами действия. Сказуемые согласованы в роде с разными подлежащими.

**Предложение сложноподчинённое. Запятая перед «куда» нужна.**

Ср.:

*― Были вещи, ― перевел доктор. ― **Не знаю, куда делись.** Давно было.* [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944)]

Comment: *Я-то считал, что она просто совершила описку* — я тоже, причём без капли сомнения)))

Comment: @slava1947   Уважаемый  slava!   Cпасибо вам за прекрасно организованный спектакль!
 Я получила большое удовольствие и от его просмотра, и от своего участия в нем. Материал тщательно подготовленный, роли подобраны и сыграны прекрасно,  искренне, с душой. Каждый человек был на своем месте.  Трудно даже выделит лучшего актера — все, безусловно, хороши. Правда, не знаю, насколько удачно я сама вписалась в коллектив, ну да ладно, зрители простят.

Comment: Может, только масштаб работы не слишком оправдан в моих глазах, то есть общая идея спектакля кажется мне до конца неясной.  Я всего лишь обычный человек со своими взглядами, мнениями, предпочтениями. А также с правом совершать ошибки, исправлять или не исправлять их. Частная жизнь, одним словом, и даже такая искренняя опека и желание мне «помочь» исправиться, стать лучше, стать такой, как вы все, – даже такое внимание не всегда бывает приятно. Но в любом случае спасибо всем участникам, и я по возможности сделаю нужные для себя выводы.

Comment: _Sharon: Уважаемый slava! Cпасибо вам за прекрасно организованный спектакль! Я получила большое удовольствие и от его просмотра, и от своего участия в нем. Материал тщательно подготовленный, роли подобраны и сыграны прекрасно, искренне, с душой. Каждый человек был на своем месте…_ ===  Гм… По-моему, я ничего **не организовывал.**

Comment: Со стороны это  выглядит именно так, потому что у спектакля, так слаженно организованного, должен быть режиссер.  А других вариантов у меня нет.  :))  Но если я ошиблась, то извините. Но в самоорганизацию я не верю.

Comment: @Sharon когда кто-то неправ, а остальные правы, это для того, кто неправ, и впрямь может выглядеть спектаклем. Но это самоорганизация. Если кто-то начнёт утверждать, что дважды два равно пять, ему всякий скажет, что он неправ, без каких либо между собой согласований. (Это безотносительно к данному вопросу, в него я встревать не хочу.)

Comment: Мои дорогие друзья,  правые и неправые,  любимые и не очень.  все эти мотивы повторяются из года в год, и утомили меня БЕСКОНЕЧНО. Не хочу ни с кем разговаривать, забили вы "белую ворону" камешками окончательно. ОБЕТ МОЛЧАНИЯ на полгода, каково, а?  :)  Отвечаю на вопросы когда хочу и что хочу, в комментариях больше не участвую. Друг друга теперь учите и воспитывайте.

Answer (score 1):

Думается мне, что ответ на вопрос — ставить или не ставить запятую? — во многом зависит от контекста. Отсутствие запятой можно отнести к авторской пунктуации.
А вот непридуманные отрывки, и в них запятая — есть.

> — Иван Иваныч, спросите у него, были ли в лодке еще какие-нибудь вещи? И если были, то какие и куда они делись?
> — Были вещи, — перевел доктор. — **Не знаю, куда делись**. Давно было. Может быть, десять лет прошло.
> [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана](https://www.booksite.ru/localtxt/kav/erin/kaverin_v/dva/dva_kapitana/23.htm)

*Папочка, открой свои глазки, посмотри на свою доченьку, как она тебя любит!.. Ты мне куклу купил, а я ее потеряла, **не знаю, куда подевалась**!..* (Александр Проханов. Господин Гексоген).

Comment: *А вот непридуманные отрывки, и в них запятая — есть* — потому что здесь нет переносного (фразеологического) значения.

Comment: То есть не в этих примерах нет, а нет в принципе.

Answer (score 0):

Устойчивое сочетания есть такое сочетание, которое не конструируется по правилам грамматики говорящим, а используется целиком ввиду того, что оно устоялось в речи и массово используется людьми. Устойчивость сочетания не зависит от интонации, ударения и подобного. Из-за другого произношения оно не станет устойчивым, а станет, когда начнет массово использоваться людьми.